# Reading Jp2 compression level using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, compression, jpeg-2000

Is the compression quality level used to create a JPEG2000 image stored somewhere inside the file, and how to read it?

I would like to know if my images where generated using a lossless compression or lossy, and if yes what was the level used?

I imagined a tag in the header would be present but I can't find it.

Can this be done in ArcPy?

Comment: What does your research into using ArcPy so far indicate?  An ArcPy question should always include a code snippet so that we can see what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: Lossless images are compressed with 5x3 kernel, with reversible color component transformation, and with no quantization and thus they can be identified. Quality level comes from the slope value where the bit steam was cut. I have no idea if it is saved into the metadata. I suppose it can be computed by studying how much the last bits in bit stream are improving the quality.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I finally found the information inside the DIMAPv2 xml attached to the images.